# Need help with my MANOVA

Tags: r, assumptions, manova

First a short description of my dataset:

- I have 8 independent binary variables with the values 0 and 1 (say something about characteristics of the subject line of an e-mail)
- I have 7 dependent continuous variables (open rate, click rate, click to open rate, unsubscribe rate, abuse rate, gross conversion and net conversion)

My question is in what way do my IV's affect the response on the newsletter (existing of 7 DV's).

I thought conducting a MANOVA with all IV's and DV's together would be a good option.

Problem 1: Click rate is highly correlating with click to open rate and the two conversion DV's as well. So I decided to leave net conversion and click rate out. Is this a good decision?
[image: Correlation plot of the continuous DV's]

Problem 2: I figured out (after many struggles) how to run the MANOVA with my IV's and DV's, but I have to check for assumptions as well.

1) To check for multivariate normality I did the m.shapiro test, but this gives me the following error:

```
mshapiro.test(cbind(df_multi$Open_rate, df_multi$click_to_open_rate, df_multi$unsubscribe_rate, df_multi$abuse_rate))

Error in solve.default(R %*% t(R), tol = 1e-18) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.49933e-21
```

What does this mean?

I tried to do a QQ plot as well:
[image]

Does this mean I am not allowed to do a MANOVA? And what can I do about this? Or should I go for an entirely other test?

2) The homogeneity of variance test is not working either (I tried the Bartlett test but this does not work).

Comment: +1 just for describing the data!  Welcome to the site ! I am not convinced that `manova` is the right model, an SEM model may be better. However, to answer your actual questions, problem 1: maybe ! Problem 2, the error seems like a problem with the arrangement of your data. For `k` variables with `n` observations, the input to `mshapiro.test` should be a `k x n` matrix.  Bartlett's test is sensitive to non-normality, so that may be a problem, but without further info it is hard to say.

Comment: Who you are and how much you need help don't play a part here. See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-k-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately/4481#4481 It's not that we've not been there ourselves, but that you weaken your question by special pleading.

Comment: @NickCox let's be nice, as per the SO recent announcements :D

Comment: @NickCox, sorry for that! Is this just about the title of the post or did I formulate anything else wrong? Can I still change the title? Or will this topic be closed now?

Comment: @LisaKleinhuis Your question's fine. Please read the link for details no longer biting.

Comment: @RobertLong I've linked to upvoted good advice.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by rate (a term which means different things to different people) you may need a different model. Specifically, if they are counts some sort of Poisson model might be better.